# Rails ActiveRecord Behaviour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I wanted to understand how ActiveRecord works in the following scenario.

```
@messages = Message.joins(:users).where("some condition").uniq
```

now if i use `@messages.sum(:url_view_count)`
I see the query is interpreted again as

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM ("messages"."url_view_count")  FROM "messages" INNER JOIN "users" ON .. and conditons
```

why the whole query starts again? Can it do `sum` among the filtered out `@messages` right?

And,  why the interpreted query is `DISTINCT SUM(url_view_count)'?

Doesn't this mess up my result?

If the column `url_view_count` has `1, 1, 2`. I am expecting `1+1+2 = 4`,
But this query gives me result as `1+2 = 3`.

Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

1. @messages is an ActiveRecord::Relation. It's lazy evaluated. So @messages does not execute any SQL commands until it has too. In this case, when you call `sum` on it.
2. You have `DISTINCT` because you chained `#uniq` there. But I don't think it matters here, because it modifies `SUM` here (the SQL here selects SUM, not messages).

Comment: `Message.pluck(:url_view_count).compact.count` , i get 46.
`Message.pluck(:url_view_count).uniq.compact.count` i get 10.
so we understand many of values are repeated. Now the `.uniq.sum(:url_view_count)` from query in question is ignoring repeated values.

Comment: `#pluck` returns Array, and the `#uniq` here is an array method, but that in your question is an ActiveRecord::Relation method. You'll see that these are very different queries.